# Why 'xdg-open google-chrome' wont work?

Tags: 12.04

When I type `google-chrome` in the terminal it works. `xdg-open google-chrome` doesn't.
Why is this so? I need to do this so that I can run Chrome without keeping the terminal open, which `xdg-open google-chrome` allows me to do.

Comment: `xdg-open` is for opening a file. Not for applications.

Comment: wrong! you can open applications as well. Try `xdg-open firefox`. And btw, "Everything in linux is a file"

Answer (score 2):

XDG-open is for opening the "right" application for the file type. In your case you like to run the application `google-chrome` in the background - XDG-open is not used for this purpose.

Instead, use your shell (assuming Bash here) to have the program run in the background:

```
nohup google-chrome &
```

Explanation: appending `&` makes it run in the background (you'll get your shell back) while `nohup` will keep the application open (disowns). See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57633/23363) in [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4004/23363) for more details.

Comment: `prog & disown` seems to work well. But not `nohup prog &`. It does not display the prompt. `prog &; disown` does not work.